# Website layout different between jsfiddle and cloud 9's browser

Tags: html, css

I am using Cloud 9 IDE for developing a website.

However site layout is different.

Code snippet is provided

When I am using the inbuilt browser in Cloud 9, I am getting the html page as shown in stack snippet. However, when I maximize it(cloud 9 browser) and see it in firefox, I get different layout[image]

The menu is coming on the top of image.

I am not sure, why it is happening.

However question is, how can I make sure, that website layout is same whether I use stack snippet, cloud 9's inbuilt browser or I maximize Cloud 9's browser in my firefox.

Please let me know, if you need additional information.

```css
.headerSection{
    background-color: #FECB6E;
 margin-bottom:1px;
 margin-top:1px;
}

#active{
    border-top: thin solid gray;
    border-left: thin solid gray;
    border-right: thin solid gray;
    background:#E6E6E6;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://img11.deviantart.net/3e48/i/2010/044/2/8/programming_oop_wallpaper_red_by_hexeno.png');
  width:100%;
  height:250px;
}

#footnote #wormHole {    
     padding-top:0;
     overflow:hidden;
     width:100%;
     height:20%;
     color:#000;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
     text-align:center;
     z-index:1;
     opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="headerSection">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
       <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
       <li><a href="https://knowledge-portal-tusharsaurabh.c9.io/select.php" target="_blank">Programming</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
       <li><a href="https://knowledge-portal-tusharsaurabh.c9.io/submitalink.php" target="_blank">Submit A Link</a></li>
       <li id='active'><a href="https://knowledge-portal-tusharsaurabh.c9.io/generalfeedback.php" target="_blank">Feedback</a></li>
      </ul> 
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
         <h1 id="wormHole">WORMHOLE.</h1>
         <p id="footnote">Web portal to Programming.</p>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is called **responsiveness** and is one of the <s>horrible things</s> main features of Bootstrap.
In this case, it is the following selector that causes the navbar to change:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
{
    .col-md-1,
    .col-md-2,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-md-4,
    .col-md-5,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-md-7,
    .col-md-8,
    .col-md-9,
    .col-md-10,
    .col-md-11,
    .col-md-12
    {
        float:left;
    }
}
```

If you don't want that, you can add `.col-md-4{float:none !important}` to your CSS:

```css
.col-md-4{
    float:none !important;
}

.headerSection{
    background-color: #FECB6E;
 margin-bottom:1px;
 margin-top:1px;
}

#active{
    border-top: thin solid gray;
    border-left: thin solid gray;
    border-right: thin solid gray;
    background:#E6E6E6;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://img11.deviantart.net/3e48/i/2010/044/2/8/programming_oop_wallpaper_red_by_hexeno.png');
  width:100%;
  height:250px;
}

#footnote #wormHole {    
     padding-top:0;
     overflow:hidden;
     width:100%;
     height:20%;
     color:#000;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
     text-align:center;
     z-index:1;
     opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="headerSection">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
       <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
       <li><a href="https://knowledge-portal-tusharsaurabh.c9.io/select.php" target="_blank">Programming</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
       <li><a href="https://knowledge-portal-tusharsaurabh.c9.io/submitalink.php" target="_blank">Submit A Link</a></li>
       <li id='active'><a href="https://knowledge-portal-tusharsaurabh.c9.io/generalfeedback.php" target="_blank">Feedback</a></li>
      </ul> 
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
         <h1 id="wormHole">WORMHOLE.</h1>
         <p id="footnote">Web portal to Programming.</p>
       </div>
 </div>
```